# Change <selected> value programmatically

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to change the select value programmatically.

This is my select tag:

```
<select ng-options="tower as tower.address for tower in towers " ng-model="itemTower" ng-change="changeTower();"></select>
```

After this select tag i have a button to call a function. This function should change the ng-model, and change the option selected instead. But it is not working!

This is my function:

```
$scope.editTower = function (){
    $scope.itemTower = 2; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to set the `itemTower` to an index, but it should be an object according to your `ng-options`, could you try to do the following:

```
$scope.editTower = function (){
    $scope.itemTower = $scope.towers[2]; 
}
```

Comment: Thats it! U rock bro! Thanks!